# SSMS - Querying multiple servers in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

So I've got this query that I'm trying to run in SQLCMD mode in SSMS:

```
:CONNECT SERVER1
  select * 
  from [SERVER1].DB1.dbo.Project
  where id not in 
  (
      :CONNECT [SERVER2]
      select distinct id from [SERVER2].DB2.dbo.Project 
  );
```

however getting this error, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

> Fatal scripting error. Cannot open connection specified in the SQLCMD
>   script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid for SQLCMD queries, you won't be able to do what you're attempting this way.

Connect to the linked servers through their 4-part naming like you have. Take the control language out of it. There is no need for SQLCMD here.

```
  select * 
  from [SERVER1].DB1.dbo.Project
  where id not in 
  (
      select distinct id from [SERVER2].DB2.dbo.Project 
  );
```

Comment: I previously tried this but was getting 'Invalid object name' error on the select query object depending on which db it was connected to. So for example, if I opened a new query window on Server1.db1, then I would get Invalid Object name Server2.db2.. if I opened a new query window from Server2.db2, it would then give 'Invalid object name' for Serer1.db1. I also tried to USE Master at the top but that didnt make a difference.

Comment: Do you have the linked servers setup as the name Server1 and Server2?

Comment: I do not. Is there another way to do so? Because I get a message saying I don't have permission to perform the action(sp_addlinkedserver) to my localdb

Comment: The reason it isn't working is due to not having the linked servers. Those will need to be added in order for this to work. It sounds like a permissions issue, you'll need to have permissions to create these objects. If you can't, please ask your sysadmin or DBA to create it for you :)